# Interpreting Cortex M4 hard fault error debug info

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, keil, cortex-m, nxp-microcontroller

Sorry - this is long! I'm sure I'll get some TL;DRs. :/

I'm not at all new to the world of Cortex M3/4; I have encountered plenty of hard fault errors in the past and, without exception, they have been due to stack overflow on FreeRTOS. However, in this case, I'm really struggling to track down a hard fault on a system that has someone else's old code that I have slightly modified.

I have a system with an LCD and touch screen. We have new hardware, which is almost identical to the old hardware other than it changing from an LPC1788 to a drop-in equivalent LPC4088 and the touch screen being I2C rather than SPI.

I'm using Keil uvision (which is new to me) with an NXP4088 which is an M4 core and Keil RL-ARM RTOS (also new to me) which is using C/C++ hybrid, the C++ also not something I have much experience with. On top of this, there is Segger emWin (which I've never used)  closed source code where it always  seems to be crashing. It will render a few screens, read the touch screen buttons etc and then fall over. Sometimes it falls over immediately though.

I have followed this:

http://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf

I have attached a picture of the debugger/IDE when it crashes below (click to enlarge).

[image]

When it crashes, the highlighted green task in the OS is, without exception, ApplicationTask (which I have not modified).

If I am reading the info correctly the Keil uvision debugger tells me that the stack being used was the MSP stack which is at address 0x20003238. There's a memory dump below:

[image]

If I understand correctly, this means that R0, 2, 3 and 12 are 0, the program counter is at 0 as are LR and PSR. However, this goes against what's in the Call Stack + Locals window in the first picture. If I right click on the 0x00005A50 underneath ApplicationTask:4 and choose caller code, it itells me it is

```
BL.W GUI_ALLOC_UnlockH
```

Which is in the emWin binary blob I think.

However, if I look at 0x20001B60 (which is the *PSP* stack value) as below:

[image]

That seems to tally up much better with what the Call Stack + Local Window tells me. It also seems to tell me that it's crashing in emWin and extensive Googling shows that Segger always completely wash their hands of any possibility their closed source code could be at fault. To be fair, it's unlikely as it's been working OK until I modified the code to use an I2C touch screen interface rather than SPI. However, where it's crashing (or seems to be) is nothing to do with the code I have modified.

Also, this window below:

[image]

Gives the BFAR address as 0xF00B4DDA and the memory manager fault address as 0xF00B4DDA. I don't know whether I should be interpreting this as to being the issue.

I have found a few other posts around the web, including one staggeringly similar one to this here on Stack Overflow (but all have no solution associated with them) where people have the same issue.

So, my questions are:

1. Am I reading this data correctly and understanding the Keil document I linked to? I really feel I must be missing something with this MSP/PSP issue.
2. Am I using the caller code function with uvision correctly? The bit where I right click on Call Stack + Locals' address below ApplicationTask:4 and it always seems to take me to some Segger code I can't examine and surely isn't what's at fault.
3. Should I really be reading the issue as a bus fault address with it trying to read from or write to 0xF00B4DDA which is reserved space?
4. I tried implementing a piece of code such as this:

https://blog.frankvh.com/2011/12/07/cortex-m3-m4-hard-fault-handler/

But that just stops the whole system running properly and ends up in at BKPT instruction in some init code. On top of this, I am not convinced this kind of thing would tell me any more than uvision does, other than it showing me slightly faster and with zero effort. Am I right in this latter assumption?

Comment: Call stacks etc are probably not very relevant. 1) Put a breakpoint on the hard fault handler. 2) Run until crash. 3) Look at the instruction trace.

Comment: Not that this answers the question about interpreting hard fault info directly, but I would suspect stack overflows or buffer overruns causing the core to go off in the weeds, making the hard fault info mostly useless.   Enlarge all of your stacks (if you can) and/or put fences around them.  Then do something similar to your arrays you're using.   Another option (which is more painful) is take a memory dump before and after your crash, then diff in a tool that lets you winnow down the expected differences and maybe get a whiff of what's misbehaving.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you literally go back to the old SPI code and it seems to work fine on your new hardware? If so, take a very long hard look at what you changed - the I2C code and interrupt handlers - for side-effects/stack depth needed. And yes enlarge the stacks see if it has any effect. Another trick I've used when desperate and suspecting stack is to make sure RAM is zeroed before everything starts, then after a crash have a look at the memory areas for the stacks and look how far down the non-zero memory goes because that reflects the maximum stack depth actually used.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had already tried increasing the stack sizes by 100 bytes and that made no difference (I was sure I'd written that, but I rewrote the post so many times I lost track). I will go and try the old SPI code and maybe try inserting some dummy key presses as well, as it's changing from one screen to another that really seems to make it crash.

Comment: @Lundin. I have tried to trace it though from the hard fault handler, it's this where I gleaned the info that it was crashing in the Segger binaries.

Comment: I'm not talking about deciphering the stack pointer, call stacks, registers etc through some manual detective work. I'm talking about telling the debugger to spit out the instruction trace buffer from the CPU so you can see exactly which code line that caused the crash. This is one of the reasons you are using M3 and not M0 in the first place, yes?

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing or not. If you go back to the original post, there is a picture of the IDE after it has crashed. The green highlighted bit shows call stack and locals. Those addresses directly underneath ApplicationTask:4 are, I believe (IF I am interpreting the data correctly) the few calls before it crashes. I don't know how to glean further information than that, I would be delighted to learn there was a way to get more information from the the debugger.

Comment: As far as I know the reason they picked an M4 (previously M3) was to do with having the processing power an M0 would not give.

Comment: Turns out, it was a data bus issue on the SDRAM. Two of the lines were not connected correctly. Sigh. I do think it would be useful to know answers to the original questions for future reference though.